# Upgraded IdentityServer4 - Checking for expected scope openid failed

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

All started with me upgrading .Net Core 2.1 to Core 3.1, for that I also upgraded IdentityServer4 v2.3 to v4.
There were a lot of changes in the database in terms of migrations as well as dependencies.
All working, except that I now get the following error when tried to login using an external provider. (for now we only use external login provider, in this case Google)

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator[0]
      Checking for expected scope openid failed
{
        "ValidateLifetime": true,
        "AccessTokenType": "Jwt",
        "ExpectedScope": "openid",
        "Claims": {
          "nbf": 1601023633,
          "exp": 1601023933,
          "iss": "xx-local",
          "client_id": "xx",
          "sub": "89e9001c-dda2-4938-8f3f-4285b160ac42",
          "auth_time": 1601023633,
          "idp": "google",
          "email": "xxxxx@xxxx.com",
          "roles": "tech",
          "iat": 1601023633,
          "scope": [
            "cc",
            "offline_access"
          ],
          "amr": "google"
        }
      }
```

Well the error says it's missing a required scope which is OpenID so I made sure it is added to my client when created the client and checked it on the database as well

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "xx",
                ClientName = " xx Portal",
                AllowedGrantTypes =
                    {
                        GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword, "external"
                    },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = { },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { },
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "cc"
                },
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 300,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding
            },
```

I have also created the ApiScopes and Resources to represent the scopes, tehy are also registered in the startup.cs

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("cc", "CC", new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Subject, JwtClaimTypes.Email }),
        };
    }


    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
    {
        return new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope(name: "cc",   displayName: "CC"),
        };
    }


    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }
```

Edit:

I just noticed that in discovery document, in the list of supported scopes I don't have any of the OpenId or Profile

```
  "scopes_supported": [
    "cc",
    "offline_access"
  ],
```

I am using EF to manage the resources and configuration.

I also checked the other posts here, and similar ones but unfortunately none of the helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create [ApiScopes](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api_scope.html?highlight=apiscopes#defining-api-scope-in-appsettings-json) to represent the scopes that the use can request access to. In earlier version your scopes was tied to ApiResources.

So, in v4 you have **IdentityResources** and **ApiScopes** to represent the scopes the user can request access to.

See this link:

- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4592

One other thing, see this [source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/Options/DiscoveryOptions.cs):

In it there's two configuration options that controls if what is included in the discovery document:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Show identity scopes
    /// </summary>
    public bool ShowIdentityScopes { get; set; } = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Show API scopes
    /// </summary>
    public bool ShowApiScopes { get; set; } = true;
```

Perhaps the ShowIdentityScopes is false and that's why you don't see them?

Comment: Thanks, apologies I didnt put enough details in my og post, I have done all those already but nothing changed. As I mentioned in the edit of the post, I don't have OpenID or Profile in my supported scopes list in discovery document

Comment: You ned to add the openid and profile scope to your identityresource as before, and as well to your client definition.

Comment: Sure, I added OpenId and Profile to my ApiScopes and that resolved the issue. However when checked the Discovery Doc the supported_claims is now empty!

Comment: the two scopes should be added to the indentityResource, and not the AopScopes. You otherwise I guess will get the profile information into the access token. It should go into the ID-token and hence be referenced in the ID-token

Comment: But I already have them there, (please see the edit) if I don't put them in the ApiScope they don't appear in the discovery doc and as the result I get eh same error!

Comment: ah it's working , so I removed what I added to the apiScopes, and made sure the IdentityResources was registered in the startup.cs  , Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, yeah saw those options before, but my issue was that I was not registering them with the IdentityServer at all which is resolved now :)